# UIImageView user interaction enabled but still to tap gesture recognition

Tags: uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I try to get the following working:

```
vw = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [ass.match.ch.shots intValue]*(50+spacer), 20)];

for(int i =index;i<index+[ass.match.ch.shots intValue];i++){
    Results *theRes = [[ass.mem.results allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(a*(50+spacer), 0, 50, 50)];
    if([theRes.singleresult intValue] > 0){
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hit.png"]];
        [img.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];
    }else{
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nhit.png"]];
        [img.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    }

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];


    img.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [img setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
    [img.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(-1.0, -1.0)];
    [img.layer setShadowOpacity:0.5];
    [img addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [vw addSubview:img];
    a++;
}

[vw setCenter:CGPointMake((self.view.frame.size.width-200)/2,150)];
[vw setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[self.view addSubview:vw];
```

But this function is not getting called when I tap on any of the created ImageViews and I don't know why:

```
-(IBAction)imageTapped:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"Test"); }
```

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out by myself:

```
[vw bringSubviewToFront:img];
```

was the solution. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your function, here is your solution..

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(50,50,70,70);
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(nextview:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

}

```
-(void) nextview:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"tapped");
}
```

working perfectly., hope this helps..

Comment: Okey I replaced the UIImageView with a UIButton and I can see that I can not Tap the Button. The Button is overlapped by a view, but I don't know which view it is...

Comment: if you have replaced with button then use this code [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(methodName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  Here is your function (void)mthodName:(id) sender

Comment: if you are using UIButton then no need to use UITapgestureRecognizer. Try above Edited code., working perfectly